# How can I extract one value using another value in json in robot framework

Tags: json, python-3.x, robotframework

As part of verification in Robot Framework, I have following data (stored as ${resp}) as get request response:

```
{
   "numberOfElements": 2,
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "accId": "123456789",
         "total": 13,
         "isEnabled": false
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
         "accId": "987654321",
         "total": 52,
         "isEnabled": false
      }
   ],
   "last": true
}
```

From the above json, I want to extract id whose accId is 123456789. How can I use condition parameters to search for a value using any other value from the json.
I have implemented this code for verifying numberFfElemets

```
${json_resp} =    Set Variable    ${resp.json()}
${numberOfElements}  set variable  ${json_resp['numberOfElements']}
should be equal as numbers  ${numberOfElements}  2
```

Comment: What have you tried already and what did you observe?

Comment: like mentioned by  @A.Kootstra, people are willing to help in Stack Overflow as long as you show what you've tried and how you failed to achieve your goal. This helps to understand what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Edited for the i have tried.... Please check now

Comment: Does this example code work as expected for you?

Comment: Initially I used this approach for verifying the numberOfElements. But now I want to verify the id related to specific accountId. That is why I need your help.

Comment: I have used "$..[?(@.accId=='123456789')].id" for verifying the same thing using jmeter. But not able to implement it in robot framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the following solution to this problem and it works for me :

```
${uuid}=  set variable
:FOR  ${i}  IN  @{json_resp['data']}
\   ${uuid}=  run keyword if  '${i['id']}'=='123456789'     get uuid with id   ${i}
    log to console  ${uuid}
```

```
Get UUID With Id
    [Arguments]  ${content_body}
    ${uuid}=  Get From Dictionary  ${content_body}  uuid
    [Return]  ${uuid}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple step try to convert your json to dictionary and loop thought dictionary.

```
 ${json_resp} =    Set Variable    ${resp.json()}
 ${json}=    evaluate    json.loads('''${json_resp}''')    json
  :FOR  ${i}  IN  @{json['data']}
  \   log to Console      ${i['accId']}
```

Then you should can access to `accId`.

Comment: Tried this method, I am getting this error as response json contains single quotes
failed: JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: what is your actual request you got ?

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code

'Exit for loop' help to not rewrite ${id} to none

```
    *** Test Cases *** 
   Test1
        :FOR  ${i}  IN  @{json_resp()['data']}
        \   ${id}=  run keyword if  '${i['accId']}'=='123456789'     Get Id   ${i}
        \   run keyword if   '${i['accId']}'=='123456789'    Exit For Loop
            log to console  ${id}
    
    *** Keywords ***
    Get Id
        [Arguments]  ${content_body}
        ${idf}=  Get From Dictionary  ${content_body}  id
        [Return]  ${idf}
```